# Reverse Screencast? Show phone screen on Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, screencast

I'm searching a way to develop an app to show iOS/android screen on the google glass, but I did'nt find anything,
as we are already able to display glass screen by using screencast on phone with MyGlass app, why the reverse would'nt be possible?

Comment: WHY are you trying to get a "high-res, big screen" piece of information on Google Glass?  Let's look at what is best done on Glass .. it is not a universal high-res high-interaction display device.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, 3rd party apps cannot capture a phone screen on both iOS and Android. On Android, you need READ_FRAME_BUFFER permission which is "signature|system" protection level. On iOS, you need to use some private framework/api to capture the screen. That means Apple will not allow the app to be listed on the app store.